# install ImageMagic library to php

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5, pecl, imagemagick

When i try to `sudo pecl install imagick` i get this message:

```
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

And `sudo yum install php-devel` gives me broken dependencies:

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 from updates
    php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 from updates
    php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 from updates
    php-devel-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 from updates
    php55w-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
    php55w-cli-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
    php55w-common-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
    php55w-mbstring-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
    php55w-pdo-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
    php55w-pgsql-5.5.13-2.w6.x86_64 from webtatic
```

what can this be fixed?

Comment: How do you have PHP installed currently (source/yum)?

Comment: I don't know, i did not installed it. But probably yum.